# Rollup on Contact based on custom object

Tags: contact, roll-up-summary, dlrs

I have a object Donations which is a part of managed package that holds multiple donations made by a contact. Donations object has a look up relationship to Contact. I tried using DLRS on Contact to get sum of donations made by a contact in past 12 months, but there seems to be some integrations within Contact object that do no allow DLRS insert/update operation on some Contact records. I tried creating a custom object with master detail relationship to contact to hold donation total, but I'm not able to get it to work.

Can someone provide guidance how I can achieve this without breaking any integrations on Contact? I'm open to creating a new object and developing separate process to handle this to avoid breaking any integrations on Contact.

DLRS Error log

```
The formula in the "Set Street Address Type (Home)" rule or process is invalid due to the following:<br/>The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our <A href="javascript:openPopupFocusEscapePounds('https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htdoor?body=%2Ftrain%2FonlineSupport.jsp&loc=support&language=en_US&release=218.9.5&instance=CS10', 'Help', 1024, 768, 'width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no', false, false);" title="support (New Window)">support</a> page. : CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY ()
The formula in the "Set Other Address Type (Home)" rule or process is invalid due to the following:<br/>The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our <A href="javascript:openPopupFocusEscapePounds('https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htdoor?body=%2Ftrain%2FonlineSupport.jsp&loc=support&language=en_US&release=218.9.5&instance=CS10', 'Help', 1024, 768, 'width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no', false, false);" title="support (New Window)">support</a> page. : CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY ()
```

Comment: Can’t you convert the lookup to master detail?

Comment: DLRS can roll up a custom object to Contact. If it's not working in your org, you may have some other automation, or validation rules, that is causing problems. What error do you see?

Comment: @JayantDas - Cannot convert lookup to master detail since Donation object is a part of managed package.

Comment: @VBALearner You should edit your question to reflect that so that it’s clear why the relationship on the object cannot be changed.

Comment: @VBALearner Are you using the NPSP? Are the two named rules/processes also part of the NPSP or other managed package? Those are really important pieces of information to solve this issue.

Comment: @DavidReed - I'm not using NPSP. Not sure of the two named rules/processes are part of managed package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with Apex you should be able to do with an aggregate results query. You can also use a Flow to create a rollup summary.

https://salesforceweek.ly/2015/02/how-to-create-roll-up-summaries-using-flow.html